# Build release mode in Android studio

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio, release-mode

How do I build my app in release mode in Android Studio for publishing to Google Play store? It's not obvious to me. If I use the Export Signed app wizard, does it automatically build in release mode? How do I verify if the app is built in release mode successfully?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694958/how-to-set-my-gradle-for-final-release-apk/22696316#22696316